# Envio de mensajes con android studio

Tags: java, android

Saludos cordiales a todos el problema es el siguiente:

Tengo este código para enviar mensajes de texto funciona a la perfección pero me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer que cuando no se envíe un mensaje por algún problema que se presente a la aplicación en automático, reintente enviarlo de nuevo unas 3 veces.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtPhone;
EditText txtMsg;
Button btnSend; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  txtPhone = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPhone ));
  txtMsg = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMsg ));
  btnSend = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend ));

  btnSend.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {               

                 PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);

                 registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             switch (getResultCode()){
              case Activity.RESULT_OK:     
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS enviado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 break;
              case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se pudo enviar SMS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               break;
              case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Servicio no diponible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               break;
              case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PDU (Protocol Data Unit) es NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               break;
              case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF: 
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed because radio was explicitly turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               break;
             }
            }       
              }, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));

                 SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
                 if( txtPhone.getText().toString().length()> 0 &&
                     txtMsg.getText().toString().length()>0 )
                 {                      
                  sms.sendTextMessage( txtPhone.getText().toString() , null, txtMsg.getText().toString() , sentIntent, null); 
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se puede enviar, los datos son incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                }});
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
  }

 }
```

Comment: Puedes crear un contador de intentos de envío y almacenarlo en una clase estática, un SharedPreferences, una base de datos, fichero, donde te apetezca. Simplemente tendrías que ejecutar un hilo cada cierto tiempo que se encargue de realizar el envío de nuevo hasta que se alcance el límite del contador. Eso sí, lo ideal sería que cada mensaje tuviera un identificador único para poder distinguirlos entre sí. Espero que como idea te sirva

Comment: Se me ocurre que puedas utilizar recursividad en cada case de error vuelves a llamar a tu función y esta recursividad romperia cuando entre a Activity.RESULT_OK o en su defecto cuando tu contador de errores llegue a la tercera iteración.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas al parecer me queda mas claro la de M. Gress el utilizar recursividad.